# Minimal presentation length of a universal finitely-presented group?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorial-group-theory

It is a rather well known fact, that there exist universal finitely presented groups (finitely presented groups, that contain all other finitely presented groups as subgroups). It is a rather direct consequence of the following two theorems:

> Every countably-generated recursively-presented group is a subgroup of some $2$-generated recursively-presented group. (Higman, Neuman, Neuman)

> A finitely generated group is recursively presented iff it is a subgroup of some finitely-presented group. (Higman)

To prove the existence of universal finitely-presented group we need to recursively enumerate all finite presentations and then apply those two theorems consecutively to the free product of groups, described by them.

However, I would like to know, what is the "smallest possible" presentation that can describe such group.

Let's determine the question more strictly:

Suppose $\langle a_1, ... , a_n| w_1, ... , w_r\rangle$ is a group presentation. Let's define it's length as $n + \sum_{i=1}^r |w_r|$, where $|w|$ is the length of the word $w$.

What is the minimal possible length of a presentation defining a universal finitely-generated group?

Comment: It seems very unlikely indeed that anyone will know the answer to this! It might be more realistic to ask whether there is any known specific presentation with this property i.e. one that could be input to a computer.